# How to show the table created date in android database and how to delete that table according to some condition on date?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I know all stuff regarding create table and update all, and delete it.
But now i want to delete some tables whos created date is less then 2 weeks.
So can anybudy tell me how to fetch such type of tables and from there i want to delete the table whoes date is less then 2 weeks.
Please help me regarding it. . . 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to maintain one new table (creation_date) with all tables name and their creation dates

Whenever you want to delete table whose date is less then 2 weeks at that time first fetch the system's date & time. After that count the date less then 2 weeks from current date;

Using the 2 weeks later date query in the table whose contain all table name as below

```
Select table_name From creation_date Where crnt_date < date
```

Using this you can get all the table names whose created before 2 weeks

After this you can fire query for each table for delete that table like below

```
Drop Table table_name
```

Comment: That means i have to create another table which store the creation date of creating other tables with their name ? Is there any other alternamte if i dont want to create another table to maintain it. ??

Comment: please tell me if is there any other alternate ?

Comment: In my knowledge you can not get the creation date of table from sqllite

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK **sqlite** (I guess you're talking about it) does not keep table creation date as part of the database metadata accessible trough the `sqlite_master` table. But it would be trivial to create an extra table to keep track of creation dates if this is what you need.

Comment: Yes, I only concern about that tables instead of the sqlite_master table.

Comment: will you help me in this condition ?

Comment: I think you can create a trigger on sqlite_master to update the table keeping track of the dates